# Let $A,B$ be two $3\times 3$ matrices with complex entries, such that $BA^2=A^2B$. Prove that $\det(AB-BA)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

> **Problem:** Let $A,B$ be two $3\times 3$ matrices with complex entries, such that $BA^2=A^2B$. Prove that $\det(AB-BA)=0$

**attempt:**

$A(AB-BA)=A^2B-ABA=BA^2-ABA=(BA-AB)A=-(AB-BA)A$

So

$\det[(A(AB-BA)]=(-1)^3\det[(AB-BA)A]\Rightarrow |A||AB-BA|=0$. Thus, if $|A| \not=0$;

I can say $|AB-BA|=0$.

---

another approach:

$3\det(AB-BA)=\text{trace}[(AB-BA)^3]$ So we need to prove that $\text{trace}[(AB-BA)^3]=0$
i.e: let $AB=X,BA=Y$ then
$$\text{trace}[(AB-BA)^3]=\text{trace}(X-Y)^3\\
=\text{trace}(X^3-X^2Y-XYX-YX^2+XY^2+YXY+Y^2X-Y^3)=0\Leftrightarrow \\
\text{trace}(X^3+3XY^2)=\text{trace}(Y^3+3YX^2)$$.

but $$\text{trace}(XY^2)=\text{trace}(ABBA.BA)=\text{trace}(BA.ABBA)=\text{trace}(AABBBA)=\text{trace}(AAABBB)$$

and $$\text{trace}(YX^2)=\text{trace}(B.AABAB)=\text{trace}(AABAB.B)=\text{trace}(BAAABB)=\text{trace}(AAAABBB)$$

So we need to prove that $\text{trace}(ABABAB)=\text{trace}(BABABA) ?????$

Comment: My friend, it seems that you are well aware of the property $\mathrm{trace}(WZ)=\mathrm{trace}(ZW)$. Use this property one more time on your last line!!! (take $W=A, Z=BABAB$).

Comment: I have one question: why $3\det(AB-BA)=\mathrm{trace}\bigl[(AB-BA)^3\bigr]$?

Comment: $X_{3 \times 3}$ and $\text{trace}X=0$ then : $X^3-\text{trace}X.X^2+tX-det X.I=0$ So $X^3=detX.I-tX$ hence $\text{trace}X^3=\text{trace}(\det XI)=3\det X$

Comment: I would think that $AB=BA$, as the matrix $B$ and matrix $A^2$ commute, therefore $B$ and $A$ matrix also commute; thus $AB=BA$